# trouble opening a URL with wxWidgets

Tags: url, wxwidgets

I'm trying to read http://www.tiwwdty.com/v with wxWidgets and C++.  Here's what I've got:

```
  wxString urlname = "http://www.tiwwdty.com/v";
  wxURL url(urlname);
  if (url.GetError()) abort();
  wxInputStream *in = url.GetInputStream();
  cout << "in " << in << endl;
  if (!in || !in->IsOk()) return;
  wxStringOutputStream strout;
  in->Read(strout);
  string vstr = strout.GetString().ToStdString();
  cout << "vstr " << vstr << endl;
```

And the code actually segfaults in url.GetInputStream() [!?]  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Here's the backtrace (wxWidgets 3.1.4):

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff70cd75ad libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_mutex_lock
    frame #1: 0x00007fff36acdd7d CoreFoundation`CFSocketDisableCallBacks + 79
    frame #2: 0x00000001000456f3 nfl`wxSocketManagerMac::Uninstall_Callback(this=0x00000001005b42e8, socket_=0x0000000100f913a0, event=wxSOCKET_INPUT) at sockosx.cpp:274:5
    frame #3: 0x0000000100044e71 nfl`wxSocketImplUnix::DoEnableEvents(this=0x0000000100f913a0, flags=3, enable=false) at sockunix.cpp:113:22
    frame #4: 0x0000000100045d01 nfl`wxSocketImplUnix::UpdateBlockingState(this=0x0000000100f913a0) at sockunix.h:68:9
    frame #5: 0x000000010003bb94 nfl`wxSocketBase::SetFlags(this=0x0000000101857d60, flags=28) at socket.cpp:1687:21
    frame #6: 0x000000010004057b nfl`wxSocketWaitModeChanger::~wxSocketWaitModeChanger(this=0x00007ffeefbfe320) at socket.cpp:192:19
    frame #7: 0x000000010003c905 nfl`wxSocketWaitModeChanger::~wxSocketWaitModeChanger(this=0x00007ffeefbfe320) at socket.cpp:191:5
    frame #8: 0x000000010003c98d nfl`wxSocketBase::Peek(this=0x0000000101857d60, buffer=0x0000000101077000, nbytes=4095) at socket.cpp:1147:1
    frame #9: 0x0000000100034770 nfl`wxProtocol::ReadLine(sock=0x0000000101857d60, result=0x00007ffeefbfe708) at protocol.cpp:130:15
    frame #10: 0x00000001000316b4 nfl`wxHTTP::ParseHeaders(this=0x0000000101857d60) at http.cpp:261:23
    frame #11: 0x0000000100032e29 nfl`wxHTTP::BuildRequest(this=0x0000000101857d60, path=0x00007ffeefbfeea0, method=0x00007ffeefbfed48) at http.cpp:428:17
    frame #12: 0x00000001000331cd nfl`wxHTTP::GetInputStream(this=0x0000000101857d60, path=0x00007ffeefbfeea0) at http.cpp:516:10
    frame #13: 0x0000000100042ab0 nfl`wxURL::GetInputStream(this=0x00007ffeefbff018) at url.cpp:348:47
    frame #14: 0x00000001000058ee nfl`nfl_frame::check_version(this=<unavailable>) at nfl.cpp:384:27 [opt]
    frame #15: 0x00000001000052f1 nfl`nfl_app::OnInit(this=<unavailable>) at nfl.cpp:165:10 [opt]
    frame #16: 0x0000000100054cc1 nfl`wxApp::CallOnInit(this=0x0000000100f04750) at utils.mm:439:22
    frame #17: 0x00000001003986d9 nfl`wxEntry(argc=0x00000001005cb508, argv=0x000000010191fcf0) at init.cpp:491:25
    frame #18: 0x00000001003988fb nfl`wxEntry(argc=0x00007ffeefbff95c, argv=0x00007ffeefbff980) at init.cpp:519:12
    frame #19: 0x0000000100004c44 nfl`main(argc=1, argv=<unavailable>) at nfl.cpp:138:1 [opt]
    frame #20: 0x00007fff70ad7cc9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

If it matters, the web address launches fine in a browser, but wget doesn't seem to like it.  curl, however, is fine.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the backtrace at the time of the crash? Also - what is your platform and wx version?

Comment: Done and inserted into the main question.

Comment: @MattGrinberg, if cURL doesn't have issues - you better off using it directly or through the wxCURL. Did you check the socket sample?

Comment: For what it's worth, (a) the webview sample works fine and (b) the above code works fine on Windows.  At this point, I've got a compiler test to find the OS; on Apple, I invoke curl via a system call and on Windows, I use the usual wxWidgets stuff.  Very ugly but it works!

Comment: you mean the sample works on OSX? I think it uses native browser API, which is not the same as you code here.

Comment: Yes, the sample works on OSX

Comment: Like I said - I `think` it uses browser native API, which is not the same as wxWidgets stream one.

Comment: I understand.  But the bottom line is that this code should have worked, and I don't understand why it didn't.  :(

Comment: I will try to speculate the the site in question uses different encoding that of your OSX? But I maybe completely wrong here...

Comment: No, that's not it.  The site is basically bluehost, just a straight file system, and the file in question is 6 ascii characters.  I have my ugly workaround at this pont, so probably I should just go with that ... thanks for your help!